# Cannot search for "unregistered" user?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Ok, this drove me crazy for a while. I was looking for profile of Joost de Valk (clearly remembered he had answered at least once) for [plugin developers question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/who-are-the-most-trusted-plugin-developers/2406#2406), but it was absolutely not coming up in [users or search there](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users).

At last I tracked down [the answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/what-does-cat-2-5-results-mean-at-the-end-of-urls/4613#4613) and [profile](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1722/joost-de-valk) from there. Which comes up as "Unregistered User" on top.

Are they not search-able for a reason? I don't see much difference between it and regular profile, not being able to search for it only makes it confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, unregistered users cannot be found through search -- we don't consider them "full" users. For example, they can't cast any votes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably he unregistered? Then this looks like some little privacy option for me, but the profile still is there so not that private. But that's just guessing.

Comment: No, he did not register yet. You can provide an answer without logging in through OpenID. If you do that you get a cookie so you are recognized next time and can still register to "claim" your reputation.

Comment: @Jan - ah that's handy. I like it not being forced to sign up first.